# Data Class Parameters to List - Kotlin android

Tags: android, list, kotlin, data-class

I have a Kotlin data class with around 37 attributes/parameters. I'd like to get the values of all those parameters into a list. How can I do that in a clean, minimal and efficient way? I've tried searching, but haven't come across anything of the sort yet.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**

Each of the attributes/parameters is a string. I'm loading each of the strings in its own TextView in Android (Yes, 37 TextViews in a TableLayout each with their own labels. Kind of what a receipt would look like). But I don't want to do this (`textView.text = myClass.parameter`) 37 times.

Comment: you could try using reflections

Comment: @Blackbelt Ok, but how? Could you give a full answer?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve with this implementation? This might be a XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/190805

Comment: @Simulant haha. That's interesting. I've updated my question

Comment: A `Map<String, String>` would be better here, the key could be the `TextView` id

Comment: @OmarMainegra But I already have the class and I'm using it for a lot of other things as well (converting to json, deserializing etc. etc.). Also Blackbelt - I checked the reflection lib - don't see anything helpful afaik.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution using reflection

**Include kotlin-reflect**

```
// Gradle Groovy DLS
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlin_version}"

// Gradle Kotlin DLS
implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
```

**Suppose the following case**

```
data class DataClass(val a: String, val b: String, val c: String, val d: String, val e: String)

val instance = DataClass("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

DataClass::class.memberProperties.forEach { member ->
    val name = member.name
    val value = member.get(instance) as String

    findTextViewByName(name).text = value
}
```

It's up to you to implement `findTextViewByName` function